# Android sdk unable to run in eclipse even though it is functionaling well previously

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have been using eclipse with android plugin and I am doing certain applications with out any error but last evening when I had restarted my eclipse as usual, it did not start the android intact it had given me `the Location of the android sdk hav nott been set up` and I had tried checking with the android preferences where I had found the list of `SDK target` is empty, but the location to the path is correct. I could not able to solve the fault in this. Could any one help me please.

Thanks in advance

Bharath Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the SDK location once more. It's maybe an Eclipse bug...

Comment: I had done several times dude. But in vain.Its not yet all showing the SDK targets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try re-installing the ADT plugin.